# How to track banner link conversion in Google Analytics 4 using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am just trying to create funnel report for successfull transactions which are coming from banner link from our website.

Below are the steps for such kind of transactions.

1. On home page, there is a offer popup offer banner display.
2. User click on this popup and redirect to products list page.
3. User might be change search filters and updated search result will display.
4. User select the product and quantity, then proceed to next checkout page.
   Note: there are no seperate page for product details.
5. User comes to checkout page and enter the personal details and proceed.
6. Transaction completed and display summary of order.

Our application is SPA developed in Angular, and changes in steps can be track by url changes.
I have also setup the custom event for banner click tracking which is working fine.
As per my thoughts tracking got interrupted when user update the filters and new result displayed, may be I am wrong not sure.

Please help me on that.

Thank you.